# Downloaded "Rock Generator" does not show (NOTE: Noob question)

Tags: mesh

I am still very new to Blender and 2.8.

I downloaded a Rock-generator. In Mac OSX, *Preferences > Install*, but when I <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>, the file does not show, neither does it show to be selected, while other files do, and are visible with <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>  menu.

Comment: Have you activated the add-on in *Edit > Preferences > Add-ons*?

Comment: Duarte:
* Thanks for the reply. 
* "Have I activated in Edit/Preferences?" YES! and No. That's the entire problem. * While I find other ADDONS and have activated via INSTALL/Edit/Preferences, Rock Generator does NOT SHOW in that menu where it can be activated.
* Yes, I have tried both .ZIP and files UNZIP when trying to INSTALL.
* Also, SHIFT/A pulls up an ADD menu - the ADDONS are found at the bottom but NOT Rock Generator.
* Have also searched under OFFICIAL, COMMUNITY and TESTING in EDIT/PREFERENCES.

Thanks for reply. Appreciated.